# C# Dynamic Array/ index

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I am creating an array of string[] in my c# program to save location ("name","Position") of a bunch of elements. The problem is any time I had to introduce a new element I have to change the code at several places according to index of elements:

```
   string[] list = new string[4];
   list[0] = "[ELEMENT #1 NAME],[ELEMENT #1POSITION]";
   list[1] = "[ELEMENT #2 NAME],[ELEMENT #2POSITION]";
   list[2] = "[ELEMENT #3 NAME],[ELEMENT #3POSITION]";
   list[3] = "[ELEMENT #4 NAME],[ELEMENT #4POSITION]";
```

What I am looking for is something like an dynamic array so that I do not have to change the index location every time I introduce/ remove an element from list.

Comment: Why not use a class with properties Name, and Position, and then use Array or List of that class objects.

Comment: Use `List<string>` instead. You can build it dynamically, and if you need an array you can just call its `.ToString()` method.

Comment: Are the element names unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  `List<string>` as a dynamic array, it supports `IEnumerable<string>` for enumerating, or you can call LINQ and `ToArray()`.

For example:

```
var list = new List<string>();

list.Add("[ELEMENT #1 NAME],[ELEMENT #1POSITION]");

string array[] = list.ToArray();
```

However, I'd actually recommend a dictionary in this case and not a list, a dictionary will let you store key-value pairs.

For example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,int>();

dict["Element #1 Name"] = #Element #1 Position#;
```

Note that I've no real idea what type the position is, could be an `int`, a `string` or even a `Point`, but you get the idea.

You then don't need to bother with indices but refer to everything by name:

```
var el1_pos = dict["Element #1 Name"];
var el999_pos = dict["Element #999 Name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List<T>` if you want a *dynamically sized* collection and don't bother with the index. And you should also create a type with two properties (`Name` and `Position`) and have a list of that type instead of storing them as `string`. It's easier to maintain, you don't have to parse the string every time you wanna get/set the `Name` or `Position` of a particular object.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would just use a `List<String>` here. The `Add` method allows you to just add an element, no indexing required.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Test");
```

In your case, since you have "Name" and "Position" associated with each other, consider using a `List<PositionedThing>` (a custom class in other words) or a `Dictionary<String, String>` to store your mappings.

The class would look like:

```
public class PositionedThing
{
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public String Position {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("[ELEMENT #1 NAME],[ELEMENT #1POSITION]")
```

Unless I've misunderstood your question that should be what you want

Comment: Thanks Lloyd, BradleyDotNET, Selman22, stakx & fallaciousreasoning , It solved the problem, Much appreciated.